# JS - Issue with selecting childNodes from FireFox

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to select the `childNode` of an Element.
This is how I am attempting to do so:

`var postBody_elem = elem.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes['post'].childNodes['postBody'];`

I have also tried:

`elem.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[1];`

I know it is an issue with the `childNodes`, not the `parentNodes`, I have tested.

This is the simplified structure of what I am doing:

```
<section id = 'postWrapper'>                          //This is the Second Parent.
  <article id = 'post'>                               //This should be the First Child.
    <section id = 'postInfo'>
      <section id = 'postTitle'></section>
      <section id = 'poster'></section>
      <section id = 'postDate'></section>
    </section>
    <section id = 'postBody'>                       //This should be the Second Child.
    </section>
  </article>
  <section id = 'postBar'>                          //This is the First Parent.
    <img id = 'portrait'>
    <section id = 'editButton'>Edit</section>       //This is the var elem.
    <section id = 'deleteButton'>Delete</section>
  </section>
</section>
```

The reason I have to reference the `'postBody'` by navigating through parent and child nodes is because this format is iterated many times.

--This brings me to my issue, the above line of code works in Google Chrome but does not work in FireFox, I have tried many variations but the console gives me the error that it is undefined.
I have checked at the element is properly being stated, it is just a difference between the way browsers handle it I presume.

If anyone has an answer, I would like it to be on how I can refer to the element that I have shown, not a lecture on how I improperly used `id` for multiple elements, as this is not an issue in this case (to my knowledge, since it works in Chrome).

Thanks.

Comment: It's iterated many times... and you're using "unique" ids?

Comment: @Neil Yes, yes I am. Do I know why? No, but I like it.

Comment: Sorry for lecturing you, I overlooked your last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method does not work in Firefox because it seems to be non standard, the second one doesn't work because you didn't realize that childNodes also consist text nodes. To get the element you want try

```
elem.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes['1'].childNodes['3']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/UqZVn/

Comment: @MichaelMitchell the white spaces between the tags are text nodes and the count towards the child nodes of an element. In your markup the first child of `<section id = 'postWrapper'>` is a text node(the whitespace between the tags) and `<article id = 'post'>` is the second child, same goes for the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives for posterity (these work in Firefox, I don't know about support in other browsers offhand):

1. `elem.children` excludes text nodes, so `elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].children[1]` would have worked
2. You can use `elem.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('section')[4]` (0=postInfo, 1=postTitle, 2=poster, 3=postDate)
3. You can use `elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('article > section + section')` for instance
4. I think `elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild` also works

Comment: I like number one, Thanks <3.
I find I use iterating IDs for seeing which tag is which while looking in code, they are never actually used, lol